# awk not recognized in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, pipe, echo

I'm trying to do floating point arithmetic in a shell script. I learned that `awk` can do it on the command line, but the way it works there does not seem to carry over to a shell script. When I type `awk` below, it turns gray, as if to say that bash doesn't recognize it. When I run it, `$ ./script a 30 40`, I get 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = a ]
then
     echo | awk '{print $2 + $3}'
```

Comment: Hint: what does bare `echo` do in general? So what does `echo` do in your script?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = a ]
then
     echo "$@" | awk '{print $2 + $3}'
fi
```

The $2 and $3 are not related to $1 of the script but are in awk.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this if you always trust the args being passed to it:

```
$ cat script
awk 'BEGIN{ print '"$*"' }'

$ ./script 30 + 40
70

$ ./script 30 \* 40
1200

$ ./script 30 / 40
0.75
```

Note the need to escape `*` as it's a globbing char, otherwise quote the args, e.g.:

```
$ ./script '30 * 40'
1200
```

Also, with this approach you're not limited to simple arithmetic expressions:

```
$ ./script 'log(10)'
2.30259

$ ./script 'exp(10)'
22026.5

$ ./script '10^2 - sqrt(9)'
97
```